# InterfaceBuilder, changing view hierarchy and preserve constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have

```
viewcontroller - scrollview - child views
```

I want to change it to

```
viewcontroller - view - scrollview - child views
                    \
                     - fixed bottom button
```

There are many constraints created for (scrollview - child views).
What's the recommended way to change the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have:

[image: Your version]

Just copy your scrollView to another viewController. Then replace your scrollView with UIView and finally copy back scrollView as a subView.